# mouse pointer jumps to upper left corner when opening a new explorer window using watin

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, watin

Every time I create a new WatiN IE instance the mouse pointer jumps to the upper left corner of the screen and the focus switches to the new window.

I want the application to run the background so I've set the option for the new window to not to be visible:

```
Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
```

But the mouse jump and loss of focus still occur. Is there an option to disable these jumps or a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check section New Settings in http://watin.sourceforge.net/releasenotes-1-2-0-4000.html

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that :)

Answer (score 13):

The link doesn't exist anymore.
The answer seems to be :

```
Settings.Instance.AutoMoveMousePointerToTopLeft = false;
```